# Ember loading substate and images/css animation rendering

Tags: ember.js, promise, rendering, css-animations

I have a route in my Ember App which returns a promise and it takes some time to do that, so I decided to create a loading substate and it works fine except for the images and the spin loader (css animation) present in the loading substate template:

- Static Images take a while to render especially on mobile and IE where sometimes they don't show at all
- The CSS animation spin loader gets stuck while transitioning to the actual route and again on mobile sometimes it doesn't show at all.

What could be a solution to show a loading substate static template that is very smooth and that, once the model has been loaded, it disappears without any lag/freeze of my css animation or slow rendering of my images?

We are talking about 5 very small images...

Thanks guys

Comment: .spinicon {
   animation: spin 2s infinite linear;}

Comment: I am already using css3 animation, but the problem seems to be with the transitioning to another route. the spinner stops then goes again then stops and so on... If I load the same animation on a normal page, it works just fine. It seems to have problem whith the loading substate when is pushing stuff to the template from a promise. Any help?

Comment: It's really hard to provide help without any code written by you. This should work perfectly =). Could you post some snippets of what you're doing and where it goes wrong?

Comment: Are you using a regular REST Adapter, or something else? I've had issues with loading state animations recently that I feel are related to using a local storage adapter.